# Change Custom UIButton's BG Color on Any Press in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I have a custom UIButton (SelectionButton) and am wondering how I can make it so the background color changes after being pushed -- causing it to remain that color for each instance of SelectionButton that has been pressed.

Can I do this in a line of code that will work for every SelectionButton without having to code it one at a time in an IBAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you the following solution. Make an extension to UIButton class:

```
extension UIButton {
override public var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if self.selected {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            }
            else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            }
    }
}
```

}

and than in the code connected to UIButton's TouchUpInside (or anothe event) just put:

```
@IBAction func myButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
}
```

Comment: As noted, I'm doing this a custom class called SelectionButton. When I replace UIButton with SelectionButton in line 1, I get errors for UIColor being an unresolved identifier (which doesn't make sense to me.. since SelectionButton is a subclass of UIButton)

Comment: I just tried this... I made a:  class SelectionButton: UIButton {...} and put the code from the extension to this new classs. Having no issues with UIColor. I suggest you to check the import list...

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot assign to property: sender is a 'let' constant." I looked this up, no solution popping out. Still looking

Comment: It is strange. I need to take a look at the code. I don't know why you change sender. It is fine to change properties in the object that sender points to.

Comment: The issue was obvious with fresh eyes.. I needed to change (sender: UIButton) in the IBAction to (sender: SelectionButton) to reflect the custom sub-class. Updated the answer and checking it off. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution whic may fit your needs better.

Here is the class Selection button:

```
class SelectionButton: UIButton {
override var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if self.selected {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }
        else {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }
}
```

}

and the code that will create a button instance programmatically:

```
    @IBAction func createSelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let myButton = SelectionButton()
    myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 25)

    self.view.addSubview(myButton)
    myButton.setTitle("My Selection Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
    myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    myButton.addTarget(self, action: "clickButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
```

and finally clickButton function pointed by selector:

```
    func clickButton(sender: SelectionButton) {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
}
```

Please kkep in mind that slector syntax has been changeg in latest version of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you -

```
let discoverButton:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:100 , y: 40.0, width: 360.0, height: 70.0 ))
        discoverButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "discover-white.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        discoverButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "discover-blue.png"), forState: UIControlState.Focused)
         discoverButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "discover-blue.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        discoverButton.addTarget(APP_DELEGATE, action:#selector(YourClassName.MenuButtonsPrimaryActionTriggered(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered)
        discoverButton.userInteractionEnabled  = true;
        discoverButton.tag=101



 func MenuButtonsPrimaryActionTriggered(btn:UIButton)->Void
        {
//Action performed on button
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change colour for different states in code like

mybutton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Selected)